# Plotting number of times customer visits app

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which has unique customer id and date. 
My datframe looks like this

```
date    objectId
15/07/18    "__gb5c9e15dfc004930b8ac9d5d1df1880e"
16/07/18    "__g0b2abb9da5d646eb930c1ce9bb6df5ef"
16/07/18    "__c5ff64e5448c44fabe26e88bc0e41497"
17/07/18    "__c7b0a5824a914d7198a328cdf35c95bf"
18/07/18    "__8929216e8d534569ae6fd6701c92fc4c"
19/07/18    "__gec079853a06748a79b4d101713c1e21d"
19/07/18    "__d7f24fa5909b43f4a5282877ed4eed3e"
19/07/18    "__ga523090706304454ba581d79f366816a"
19/07/18    "__d409d75e4207409b8ea030f69b70bf83"
19/07/18    "-g940dc0277b7f46c8b7d8de195a8fd975"
20/07/18    "__d7f24fa5909b43f4a5282877ed4eed3e"
20/07/18    "__ga523090706304454ba581d79f366816a"
21/07/18    "__d409d75e4207409b8ea030f69b70bf83"
21/07/18    "-g940dc0277b7f46c8b7d8de195a8fd975"
```

I want to plot a graph where I want to count how many customers visted once,twice and so on. y axis - number of times object id gets repeated 
x axis - count of object id that gets repeated. I tried something like

```
date_df['objectId'].value_counts().plot(kind='bar')
```

Comment: Your code `date_df['objectId'].value_counts().plot(kind='bar')` not working?

Comment: It is giving different  objectID's on x axis.

Answer (score 0):

This is no good dataset to plot, because you will most likely only get a bar height of one for most entries, and since there are a lot customers, you will not get a good overview at all.

Anyway, assuming the same customer gets the same ID regardless of the day, you can put all of the IDs in a list, sort the list and then plot a histogram with number of bins = number of unique entries in the list.

```
customer_list = sorted(date_df['objectId'].tolist())
```

This list is now ready to use as input for a histogram.

EDIT: your comment "It is giving different objectID's on x axis" is actually interesting, because that is the only possible output for this kind of plotted dataset - a histogram with number of occurances on y-axis and different IDs on the x-axis.

For the plotting, it would look like

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

customer_list = sorted(date_df['objectId'].tolist())
plt.hist(customer_list, bins=len(set(customer_list)))
plt.show()
```

the set removes all duplicates, and len then gives you the number of unique items in the list. by setting the bins to that number, you get one histogram bar for every single customer.